# Unit testing a c# Windows 10 IoT core application (Error : DEP0700)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, arm, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to write some unit tests for a windows 10 IoT core application I have written for my Raspberry Pi (arm architecture). I have added a new Unit Test App project to my solution and added namespace reference. When I try to run the tests from test explorer however, I get:

> Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Windows cannot install package 29113fce-56cd-4094-9a21-ee91498c14b2 because the package requires architecture ARM, but this computer has architecture x64.

Deploying the test app to the remote machine (Pi) results in Tests running printing to the screen, however nothing happens. The tests still don't run on my machine and when i select tests on the output console it displays nothing.

Does anyone have any experience unit testing a Windows 10 IoT core application or can see anything immediately obvious I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can run the tests:

- Run the whole application in local machine (x86) and also the tests. If the app is UWP, and does not use much of RPi-specific functionality, this should be the easiest way.
- Do the remote testing, with application running on RPi. To do that, you need to install [Remote Debugging Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#remote-tools) on the target RPi board. [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasonz/2012/06/12/what-you-need-to-know-about-developing-for-windows-on-arm-woa/) describes it in more detail.